# How to access property inside a method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make the user click the "Show Question " button so as to mutate state by calling the handleQuestion(), but I'm getting the following error statement "questions Is not defined".

I want to know what am doing wrong, or is there a more realistic way of doing it

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question : [],
    };
  }

  questions = [
        {
          question: "Who is the strongest?",
          answers: {
            a: "Superman",
            b: "The Terminator",
            c: "Waluigi, obviously"
          },         
   ];

   handleQuestion(){    
     this.setState({
       question: questions
     });    
   }

   render(){    
     return (    
      <div className = "container">
       <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.handleQuestion()}>
         Show Question
       </button>    
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Always a) include the conplete code, b) format the code properly, c) use semilons to end your statements.

Answer (score 2):

Properties inside the class can be accessed using the context `this`. So, this will work fine:

```
this.setState({
  question: this.questions
})
```

The syntax you are using to declare `questions` is quite new (see [stage3 -> class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)), this might or might not be supported by your environment.

If it doesn't you could alternatively use a function wrapper like:

```
questions() {
   return [...]
}
```

And you could then do:

```
question: this.questions()
```

Or set the `questions` outside the class or inside `handleQuestion` method itself. Then you'll not require to use `this` to access the `questions`.

Comment: `You'll need to define function wrapper like`... why?!

Comment: Properties can only exists inside constructor. Outside the constructor class only allow to use method. Though, if you use `stage3` then defining properties outside constructor using `=` is fine.

Comment: nope. Thats a [class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), your answer should mention that "this is not the way" is simply not true

Comment: @8SINS It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

i have made few changes in your code and they worked fine for me just try this please read the comment in code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: []
    };
  }
  questions = { // 1. use {} bracket in place of [] you using object
    question: "Who is the strongest?",
    answers: {
      a: "Superman",
      b: "The Terminator",
      c: "Waluigi, obviously"
    }
  };
  handleQuestion() {
    this.setState({
      question: this.questions //2. hear use this.questions because you are accessing class variable   
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleQuestion()}>
            Show Question
          </button>
          {this.state.question["question"]}
        </div>

    );
  }
}
```

after this change i think your code will work fine :)

Comment: Great tip! i will check and get back to you . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css'; 
var questions =[]
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
questions=  [
{
  question: "Who is the strongest?",
  answers: {
    a: "Superman",
    b: "The Terminator",
    c: "Waluigi, obviously"
  }
}         
];
this.state = {
    question : [],
};
}

handleQuestion(){ 
  this.setState({
  question: questions
});    
}

render(){    
  return (    
      <div className = "container">
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.handleQuestion()}>
        Show Question
      </button>   
      <ul>
        {this.state.question.map((data,i)=>(

            <li key={i}>{data.question}       
              <div>a : {data.answers.a}</div>
              <div>b : {data.answers.b}</div>
              <div>c : {data.answers.c}</div>
            </li>

          ))
         }
      </ul> 
   </div> 
 ); 
 }
 }

 export default App;
```

i have made somechanges and you can check the code , run  it

Comment: @8SINS It's my pleasure. One suggestion from my side you should mark the right answer, so when  other see they can get the answer and it will help them